# C# wpf Как сделать группировку с checkbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

У меня есть ListView с группировкой по определенному ключу. У меня есть checkbox's у родителя и у элементов. Мне нужно, чтобы по нажатию на checkbox родителя, все элементы поменяли свое состояние
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть проблема при создании groupstyle для listview. Там можно привязаться через RelativeSource только к одному свойству

```
<Window x:Class="FillResources.DialogWindows.AddLanguagesWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FillResources.DialogWindows"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:FillResources.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="AddLanguagesWindow" Height="300" Width="400">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:AddLanguagesWindowViewModels />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ListView Name="lvLanguages" ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="" Width="40"  >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Code" Width="Auto" >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Code}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Expander IsExpanded="True" >
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" IsChecked="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsAllSelectedPopular, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                    <TextBlock Text=" item(s)" FontSize="22" Foreground="Silver" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: DataTrigger может помочь, его надо прибиндить к свойству IsChecked родительского чекбокса. Как до него добраться в GridView не подскажу с ходу, надо тестировать.

Answer (score 0):

При создании WPF-приложений удобно использовать реактивные расширения и их реализацию под .NET - [ReactiveUI](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI). С помощью реактивных расширений вы можете легко управлять зависимостями между частями данных и их быстрой конвертацией. Крайне советую.

Для вашего случая сделал следующий простой пример. В конструкторе я подписываюсь(this.WhenAnyValue...) на изменение RootElement(ваш родительский элемент списка) и при возникновении этого события вызываю метод ChangeAllValues. При этом для каждого элемента вызывается INotifyPropertChanged.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public SourceList<bool> Elements { get; set; }

    [Reactive]
    public bool RootElement { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Elements = new SourceList<bool>();
        Elements.Add(true);
        Elements.Add(false);

        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.RootElement)
            .Subscribe(rootValue => ChangeAllValues(rootValue));
    }

    private void ChangeAllValues(bool rootValue)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Elements.Items.Count(); i++)
        {
            Elements.ReplaceAt(i, rootValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Еще большое про реактивные расширения:

1. [Habr: Введение в ReactiveUI: прокачиваем свойства во ViewModel](https://habr.com/ru/post/303650/)
2. [Habr: Введение в ReactiveUI: коллекции](https://habr.com/ru/post/303898/)
3. [Habr: Введение в ReactiveUI: изучаем команды](https://habr.com/ru/post/305350/)
4. [Habr: DynamicData](http://DynamicData:%20%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8,%20%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20MVVM%20%D0%B8%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)
5. [ReactiveUI документация](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/)
6. [Отличный пример по DynamicData](https://github.com/RolandPheasant/Dynamic.Trader)